# Python function updating variables not passed as arguments

Tags: python, function, variables, return, arguments

The following function is supposed to sample a new variable S, and save the original value passed into the function as Sp. However, when printing the output before and after the update (which uses the step function), S = Sp always. Why is Sp also being changed although it has no relation to the function being called?

```
def sarsa_timestep(k, N, Q, pi, E, lamb, S, A):
  k += 1
  N[A, S[0] - 1, S[1] - 1] += 1
  Sp = S
  A_prime = A

  print('\nBefore sampling:', S, Sp)
  print('Using action:', A)

  # Sample next state
  S, R, terminal = step(S, A)

  print('After sampling', S, Sp)
  print('Outcome:', R)

  if not terminal:
    A_prime = pi[S[0] - 1, S[1] - 1]
    delt = R + Q[A_prime, S[0] - 1, S[1] - 1] - Q[A, Sp[0] - 1, Sp[1] - 1]
  else:
    delt = R - Q[A, Sp[0] - 1, Sp[1] - 1]
    print('Terminal.')
  
  '''
  Some unrelated code
  '''


  return S, A_prime, N, Q, k, terminal
```

Some sample output:

```
Before sampling: [5, 6] [5, 6]
Using action: 1
After sampling [5, 15] [5, 15]
Outcome: 0

Before sampling: [5, 15] [5, 15]
Using action: 0
After sampling [5, 15] [5, 15]
Outcome: -1
Terminal.

Before sampling: [6, 1] [6, 1]
Using action: 1
After sampling [6, 11] [6, 11]
Outcome: 0

Before sampling: [6, 11] [6, 11]
Using action: 1
After sampling [6, 6] [6, 6]
Outcome: 0

Before sampling: [6, 6] [6, 6]
Using action: 1
After sampling [6, 8] [6, 8]
Outcome: 0

Before sampling: [6, 8] [6, 8]
Using action: 0
After sampling [6, 8] [6, 8]
Outcome: -1
Terminal.

Before sampling: [8, 8] [8, 8]
Using action: 1
After sampling [8, 15] [8, 15]
Outcome: 0
```

The function is called in a while loop as follows:

```
terminal = False
while not terminal:
   S, A, N, Q, k, terminal = sarsa_timestep(k, N, Q, pi, E, lamb, S, A)
```

For reference: The 'step' function:

```
def step (s, a):
    
    # At each time step:
    
    # First, save the dealer's first card so that the sum can eventually be updated
    
    dealer_sum = s[0]
    
    # Player's turn

    # ACTIONS: 'hit' = 1, 'stick' = 0

    if a == 1:
        rand_card = draw_card()
        #print('Agent draws', rand_card)
        s[1] += rand_card
        
        #Terminal state associated with player's turn
        if s[1] > 21 or s[1] < 1:
            #print('Agent goes bust, dealer wins!',s[1])
            return s, -1, True
        
    #Dealer's turn
    elif a == 0:
        while dealer_sum <= 17:
            rand_card = draw_card()
            #print('Dealer draws', rand_card)
            dealer_sum += rand_card
            
        #Terminal states associated with the dealer's turn
        if dealer_sum < 1 or dealer_sum > 21:
            #print('Dealer goes bust, agent wins!')
            return s, 1, True

        if dealer_sum > s[1] and dealer_sum <= 21:
            #print('Dealer wins!')
            return s, -1, True
        
        if dealer_sum < s[1]:
            #print('Agent wins!')
            return s, 1, True
        
        if dealer_sum == s[1]:
            #print('Its a draw!')
            return s, 0, True
    
    # Return the next non-terminal state and associated reward for that step
    return s, 0, False
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning one list to another does not actually copy the list.
For example:

```
def func1(x):
  x[0] += 10
  return x

def func2(a):
  ap = a
  a = func1(a)
  print(a, ap)

a = [1, 2]

func2(a)
```

Yields the output

```
[11, 2] [11, 2]
```

To get around this:

```
def func1(x):
  x[0] += 10
  return x

def func2(a):
  ap = a.copy() # Can also use ap = a[:]
  a = func1(a)
  print(a, ap)

a = [1, 2]

func2(a)
```

Yields

```
[11, 2] [1, 2]
```